# Java 8: sort list of objects by attribute without custom comparator

Tags: list, sorting, lambda, java-8

What is the cleanest short way to get this done ?

```
class AnObject{
    Long  attr;
}

List<AnObject> list;
```

I know it can be done with custom comparator for `AnObject`. Isn't there something ready out of the box for such case?

Kind of like this:

```
Collections.sort(list, X.attr);
```

Comment: Did you look the javadoc of the comparator class ? They added a bunch of methods (and you could directly do `list1.sort(..)` by the way).

Answer (score 182, accepted):

Assuming you actually have a `List<AnObject>`, all you need is

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(a -> a.attr));
```

If you make you code clean by not using public fields, but accessor methods, it becomes even cleaner:

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(AnObject::getAttr));
```

Comment: What happens if attr is null?

Comment: Can u please share some link where I can read details about this. I want to sort using more than one attributes ( like first check atttr1, if attr1 of both obj are equal then check attr2)

Comment: @JBNizet does AnObject need to implement hascode,equals and compareTo?

Comment: No. The comparator will just call getAttr() on all the objects and compare the returned values.

Comment: Thank you for concise examples, though there is nothing wrong with data/tuple classes having exposed public fields. Thus "...clean if not using public fields" is not a universal rule.

Comment: How to determine descending or ascending for long attribute?

Comment: Thank @JB_Nizet if I need to reverse sort

Answer (score 30):

As a complement to @JB Nizet's answer, if your attr is nullable,

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(AnObject::getAttr));
```

may throw a NPE.

If you also want to sort null values, you can consider

```
    list.sort(Comparator.comparing(a -> a.attr, Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder())));
```

or

```
    list.sort(Comparator.comparing(a -> a.attr, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())));
```

which will put nulls first or last.

Answer (score 12):

A null-safe option to JB Nizet's and Alex's answer above would be to do the following:

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(AnObject::getAttr, Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder())));
```

or

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(AnObject::getAttr, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())));
```