# Finding largest subset with sum equal or less than given number without recursion

Tags: java, java-8

There is an object `Product` with property `price`, also given a `budget`.

From list of products and given budget, how can I get longest subset of products where sum of prices equal or less than budget. Only 1 product per subset is allowed. Prices and budget are always positive

For example

```
   [
      {id: 1, name: pr1, price: 1},
      {id: 2, name: pr2, price: 1},
      {id: 3, name: pr3, price: 1.5},
      {id: 4, name: pr4, price: 3},
      {id: 5, name: pr5, price: 2},
      {id: 6, name: pr6, price: 4},
   ]
```

budget = 6

Result

```
  [
      {id: 1, name: pr1, price: 1},
      {id: 2, name: pr2, price: 1},
      {id: 3, name: pr3, price: 1.5},
      {id: 5, name: pr5, price: 2},
  ]
```

Is it possible to solve this problem without recursion

Comment: It seems like this can be approached with a simple while loop.  Sort your products by price, and begin adding them to a list starting with the lowest priced product, maintaining a running total of prices.  If the next product would put the total over the budget, exit the loop.  The list will now contain the maximum number of products with a sum of prices that is <= the budget.

Comment: This is a variation of the Knapsack Problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like an interview question. example would be sort the prices so you would have {1,1,1.5,2,3,4}
Then you just keep add the item to the list while the sum is less than the budget.
Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Product> product = new ArrayList<>();
    product.add(new Product(1, "pr1", 1));
    product.add(new Product(2, "pr2", 1));
    product.add(new Product(3, "pr3", 1.5));
    product.add(new Product(4, "pr4", 3));
    product.add(new Product(5, "pr5", 2));
    product.add(new Product(6, "pr6", 4));
    Price price = new Price();  // Custom comparator that compares two Products' price, must be defined elsewhere
    Collections.sort(product, price); 
    ArrayList<Product> longest = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i < product.size(); i++) {
        if(budget - product.get(i).price > 0) {
            budget = budget - product.get(i).price;
            longest.add(product.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and since this is Java 8, you can use `product.sort(Comparator.comparing(Product::getPrice));` Further, since this is already modifying the `product` list, you may also select the subset in-place: `for(int i = 0; i < product.size(); i++) { if((budget -= product.get(i).price) < 0) { product.subList(i, product.size()).clear(); break; } }`; after that, `product` contains the result.

Answer (score 0):

As Jordan said in the comments, a greedy solution would work. Assuming a [sorted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33487282/3927528) list `products`:

```
int sum = 0;
List<Product> subset = new ArrayList<>();
for (Product p : products) {
  if (sum + p.price <= budget) {
    subset.add(p);
    sum += p.price;
  } else return subset;  // or break
}
```

By adding the cheapest products first, you guarantee you can fit as many as possible before hitting the budget.

Answer (score 0):

So here's the situation: I've written a program that DOES use recursion and sort of accomplishes what you're looking for. The only thing is that it catches the longest combination(s)/subset(s) of numbers that only exactly equal the target sum (6 in your example); I couldn't seem to figure out how to find the longest subset that was less than or equal to the target sum. Also, in your example, you have two 1's for price. If you run my program instance, you'll notice it will treat two of the subsets (more than one subset equals 6) as having the same id for 1, so they are duplicate subsets. That's another problem you could maybe fix. This program took me over a day to come up with, so even though it is faulty and uses recursion, I thought I'd post it.

```
import java.util.*;

public class SubSet_sum_problem
{
    private static ArrayList<int[]> listOfArrays = new ArrayList<int[]>();

    public static void getSubsets(double[] elements, double sum) {
       getAllSubsets(elements, 0, sum, new Stack<Double>());
    }

    private static void getAllSubsets(double[] elements, int i, double sum, Stack<Double> currentSol) { 
       //stop clauses:
       if (sum == 0 && i == elements.length)
       {
         Object[] prices = currentSol.toArray();
         double[] prices2 = new double[currentSol.size()];
         for (int index = 0; index < prices.length; index++)
             prices2[index] = (Double)prices[index];
         int[] indexes = new int[currentSol.size()];
         for(int index2 = 0; index2 < prices2.length; index2++) {    // Find common/duplicate elements in both arrays
            for(int count = 0; count < elements.length; count++) {
                if(prices2[index2] == elements[count])
                    indexes[index2] = count;
            }
         }
         for (int a = 0; a < indexes.length; a++)   // Scanning for duplicates again, this time for common indexes
         { 
           for (int b = a + 1; b < indexes.length; b++) 
           { 
             if (indexes[a] == indexes[b])   // Now we know we have duplicate indexes for the elements[] array, which isn't possible
             {
                indexes[a] = a;
                indexes[b] = b;
             }
           }  
         }
         listOfArrays.add(indexes);
       }
       //if elements must be positive, you can trim search here if sum became negative
       if (i == elements.length) 
         return;
       //"guess" the current element in the list:
       currentSol.add(elements[i]);
       getAllSubsets(elements, i+1, sum-elements[i], currentSol);
       //"guess" the current element is not in the list:
       currentSol.pop();
       getAllSubsets(elements, i+1, sum, currentSol);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
       String name[] = {"pr1", "pr2", "pr3", "pr4", "pr5", "pr6"};
       double price[] = {1, 1, 1.5, 3, 2, 4};
       double sum = 6.0;
       getSubsets(price, sum);
       int size = listOfArrays.size();
       int max = listOfArrays.get(0).length;
       for(int str[] : listOfArrays)
       {
          int theSize = str.length;
          if(max < theSize)
            max = theSize;
       }
       for(int arr[] : listOfArrays)
       {
          if (arr.length == max)
          {
             for (int index = 0; index < arr.length; index++)
             {
                int index2 = arr[index] + 1;
                System.out.print("{id: " + index2 + ", name: " + name[arr[index]] + ", price: " + price[arr[index]] + "}\n");
                if (index == arr.length - 1)
                   System.out.print("\n"); 
             }
          }
       }
    } 
}
```